# how to call a groovy function in an active choice parameter in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement where user has to select multiple resource names from the input block. I tried active choice parameter inside the user input step, and its working when I hardcode the values but the output is empty when I call a groovy function to dynamically generate the value. This function will return a list of resources names based on the environment passed earlier at the start of the job. So hardcoding the values won't be ideal for my situation. Any ideas on how to call a groovy function into the active choice parameter block?

```
pipeline {

  agent any

  stages{

    stage('test user input') {

        steps {

          timestamps {

            script {

 def userInput = input(

                parameters: [[$class: 'ChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX', description: 'Please select the values', filterLength: 1, filterable: false, name: 'testvalues', randomName: 'choice-parameter-37737065277176157', script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: '''return[

\'error\'

]'''], script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: '''def getvalues(){

return[

\'values1\',

\'values2\',

\'values3\',

\'values4\'

]

}

def value=getvalues()

return value''']]]]

                )

                println("input: " + userInput)

            }

          }

        }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: or you are returning wrong value or you have error in your code  and fallback-script/try-catch not used.

Comment: Please post a block of code and the current and expected output.

Comment: @christopher - can you update if you make it work, and if so, how?

Comment: Since the `sandbox` set to `false` maybe check for the script approvals (`<jenkins host>/manage/scriptApproval/` )as well.